# How to animate the height of a div based on content within it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, css-transitions

I am trying to create a navigation when the user hovers over the navigation links the corresponding panel will open and show its content. When the user hovers the next navigation link, the panel will adjust to the next content's height.

An example of this would be the navigation on [apple.com](https://apple.com)

**Approach 1 (css only):** 
Initially, this is how I wrote the navigation links with the content that goes with it:

```
<li class="navigation__links__item">
  <a href="#" class="navigation__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 1</a>
  <div class="navigation__links__item__panel">Nav Link 1 Content
    <ul>
       <li>something</li>
       <li>something</li>
       <li>something</li>
       <li>something</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

1. .navigation__links__item__panel starts at max-height: 0
2. then when the user hovers .navigation__links__item__trigger
3. .navigation__links__item__panel will be max-height: 80% and the transition is transition: max-height 350ms.

The problem I found with this is that when the user hovers onto another .navigation__links__item__trigger, you can see the old active panel closing and the new one opening.

**Approach 2 (javascript):** 
Then I tried doing a mouseenter/mouseleave approach. 
Using the same markup above, I added an openPanel() on mouseenter and closePanel() on mouseleave.

1. .navigation2__links__item__panel starts at max-height: 0
2. then when the user hovers .navigation2__links__item__trigger
3. .navigation2__links__item--open is added onto the same element as .navigation2__links__item. Then the panel opens up with max-height: 999px and transition: max-height: 450ms.

The problem I had with this is because it's identical with the first navigation I made where you can see the last active panel closing and the new one opening. I feel like there should be an in-between class to maybe adjust the height? But I'm not entirely sure what I would have to do. Once the cursor mouseleaves the element, should there be a setTimeout to keep the --open for a while and then find the height of the next?

**Approach 3 (javascript with different html markup):** 
In this approach, I rewrote the markup so that instead of keeping the related trigger and panel together, I separated it so that all triggers are together and all content are in one panel:

```
  <ul class="navigation3__links">
    <li class="navigation3__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation3__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation3__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation3__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 2</a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
  <div class="navigation3__panel">
    <div class="navigation3__panel__content hidden">
      Nav Link 1 Content
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation3__panel__content hidden">
      Nav Link 2 Content
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
```

1. I mapped it so that I know what .navigation3__links__item__trigger (key) is connected to which .navigation3__panel__content (value).
2. I also got the height of the .navigation3__panel__content when it is not .hidden.
3. navigation3__panel is set to height = 0.
4. When the user hovers .navigation3__links__item__trigger, it will find the correct .navigation3__panel__content, remove .hidden, get the original height at (2.) and set .navigation3__panel's height to the new height.
5. When the user hovers onto another .navigation3__links__item__trigger, it gets the height of that trigger, then .navigation3__panel height is set to the new one.

The problem I have with this one is that when I try to hover over the panel while it's open, the panel will close.

Also, I'm not sure if this is this going to be an accessibility issue? Is it better to keep the trigger and panel together like Approach 1 and 2? Or is it ok to write like Approach 3?

Here is my codepen: [codepen](https://codepen.io/jack1020/pen/YzBJZaB)

```js
//navigation 2
let activeNav2;
const navigation2 = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation2")[0];
const navLinks = navigation2.getElementsByClassName("navigation2__links__item");

for (let a=0; a < navLinks.length; a++) {
  navLinks[a].addEventListener("mouseenter", openPanel);
  navLinks[a].addEventListener("mouseleave", closePanel);
}

function openPanel() {
  console.log("open");
  
  if (activeNav2) {
    // console.log(activeNav);
    // if (activeNav != this) {
    //   activeNav.classList.remove("navigation__links__item--open")
    //   activeNav = this;
    //   setTimeout(closeNext(activeNav), 500);
    //   // activeNav.classList.add("navigation__links__item--open");
    // }
  }
  else {
    activeNav2 = this;
    activeNav2.classList.add("navigation2__links__item--open");
  }
}
function closeOpenNext() {
  
}
function closePanel() {
  console.log("close");
  activeNav2.classList.remove("navigation2__links__item--open");
  activeNav2 = null;
}


//navigation 3
const heightMap = new Map();
const linkMap = new Map();

const navigation3 = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation3")[0];
const navPanel3 = navigation3.getElementsByClassName("navigation3__panel")[0];
const navLinks3 = navigation3.getElementsByClassName("navigation3__links__item");
const navContent3 = navPanel3.getElementsByClassName("navigation3__panel__content");

let activeContent;
let currentPanelHeight = 0;

navigation3.addEventListener("mouseout", closePanel3);

for (let b=0; b < navLinks3.length; b++) {
  navLinks3[b].id = "linkItem" + b;
  navContent3[b].id = "content" + b;
  
  linkMap.set(navLinks3[b].id, navContent3[b].id);
  navLinks3[b].addEventListener("mouseenter", openPanel3);
  
  navContent3[b].classList.remove("hidden");
  let height = navPanel3.offsetHeight;
  heightMap.set(navContent3[b].id, height);
  navContent3[b].classList.add("hidden");
}

navPanel3.style.height = 0 + "px";

function openPanel3() {
  console.log("open");
 const content = document.getElementById(linkMap.get(this.id));
  
  if (!activeContent) {
    content.classList.remove("hidden");
    activeContent = content;
  } else {
    activeContent.classList.add("hidden");
    content.classList.remove("hidden");
    activeContent = content;
  }
  
  const height = heightMap.get(content.id);
  navPanel3.style.height = (height) + "px";
  
  currentPanelHeight = height;
}

function closePanel3() {
  if (activeContent) {
    activeContent.classList.add("hidden");
    let currentPanelHeight = 0;
    navPanel3.style.height = currentPanelHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}
.navigation__links {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.navigation__links__item:hover .navigation__links__item__trigger + .navigation__links__item__panel {
  max-height: 80%;
}
.navigation__links__item__trigger {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.navigation__links__item__panel {
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 350ms;
}

.navigation2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.navigation2__links {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.navigation2__links__item__trigger {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.navigation2__links__item__panel {
  max-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 350ms;
}
.navigation2__links__item--open .navigation2__links__item__panel {
  max-height: 999px;
  transition: max-height 450ms;
}
.navigation3 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
.navigation3__links {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.navigation3__links__item__trigger {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.navigation3__panel {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 350ms;
}
.navigation3__panel .hidden {
  display: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!-- navigation with just css hover -->
<nav class="navigation">
  <div class="navigation__logo">logo</div>
  <ul class="navigation__links">
    <li class="navigation__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 1</a>
      <div class="navigation__links__item__panel">Nav Link 1 Content
        <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 2</a>
       <div class="navigation__links__item__panel">Nav Link 2 Content
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
         
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
           
         </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 3</a>
       <div class="navigation__links__item__panel">Nav Link 3 Content
       <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 4</a>
       <div class="navigation__links__item__panel">Nav Link 4 Content
       <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="navigation__cart">cart</div>
</nav>

<div style="padding: 10em"></div>

<!-- navigation with mouseenter and mouseleave -->
<nav class="navigation2">
  <div class="navigation2__logo">logo</div>
  <ul class="navigation2__links">
    <li class="navigation2__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation2__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 1</a>
      <div class="navigation2__links__item__panel">Nav Link 1 Content
        <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation2__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation2__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 2</a>
       <div class="navigation2__links__item__panel">Nav Link 2 Content
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
         
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
           
         </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation2__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation2__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 3</a>
       <div class="navigation2__links__item__panel">Nav Link 3 Content
       <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
         <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation2__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation2__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 4</a>
       <div class="navigation2__links__item__panel">Nav Link 4 Content
       <ul>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
           <li>something</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="navigation2__cart">cart</div>
</nav>

<div style="padding: 10em"></div>

<!-- navigation with mouseenter and mouseleave -->
<nav class="navigation3">
  <div class="navigation3__logo">logo</div>
  <ul class="navigation3__links">
    <li class="navigation3__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation3__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation3__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation3__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation3__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation3__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation3__links__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation3__links__item__trigger">Nav Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="navigation3__panel">
    <div class="navigation3__panel__content hidden">
      Nav Link 1 Content
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation3__panel__content hidden">
      Nav Link 2 Content
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation3__panel__content hidden">
      Nav Link 3 Content
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation3__panel__content hidden">
      Nav Link 4 Content
      <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation3__cart">cart</div>
</nav>

<div style="padding: 40em"></div>
```